# Closed form way to express $a^1 + a^2 + a^3 + a^4 \cdots a^n$, given $a$ and $n$?

Tags: number-theory

Is there a way to sum up consecutive powers like this when we know the value of $a$ using a closed form expression or do we actually have to add up each one?

By closed form I mean in the same way that the sum of numbers $1$ to $n$ is $n(n+1)/2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called a geometric sum.

$$a + a^2 + \cdots + a^n = \frac{a - a^{n+1}}{1 - a}.$$

If it's infinite, then we call it a geometric series and we have

$$a + a^2 + \cdots  = \frac{a}{1 - a}$$

though this second one only converges for $|a| < 1$.  The proof is similar to the formula you mention.  Let $S = a + a^2 + \cdots + a^n$.  Now, subtract $S - aS$.

Answer (score 3):

let $$S_n=a+a^2+...+a^n$$ then $$aS_n=a^2+a^3+...+a^n+a^{n+1}$$ from first equation subtract the second then
$$S_n-aS_n=a-a^{n+1}$$
$$S_n(1-a)=a-a^{n+1}$$
$$S_n=\frac{a-a^{n+1}}{1-a}$$